# using ajax to change div - not working

Tags: php, ajax

I have a js function:

```
function updateDescriptor(subj){
    "use strict";
     var xhttp;
     xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
        }    
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "ajaxy/fred.php?q"+subj, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

fred.php is very simple (it will ultimately be a db query)

```
$returntext="<h1>hello from my first ajax thing</h1>";
echo '$returntext;
```

In the HTML is:

```
 <h1>Edit Subject Descriptors</h1>
 <div id="txtHint"><p>text hint</p></div>
<form name="subject-descriptors" action="assessment-subject-descriptors.php" method="post" class="complex-grey">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="formelement">
            <select name="subjects" class="lineInput updatetextbox" onchange="updateDescriptor(this.value)">
:
</form>
```

I know that `updateDescriptor`  is being called - I had an alert. However, the `txtHint` content is not changing so something is wrong.

Any ideas plesse?

I have been following a [w3schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp)

Comment: From where you're calling this `updateDescriptor()` function?

Comment: You have an error at `echo '$returntext;`. Use double-quotes and close them!

Comment: You're missing an `=` in your `GET` URL. Should be: `"ajaxy/fred.php?q=" + subj` ... Typo? or does `subj` start with an `=`?

Comment: Alex -- aghhhh  - there's me thinking I had missed something to do with Ajax and it was something really stupid. Sorry - and thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you need to change.

First this:

```
xhttp.open("GET", "ajaxy/fred.php?q"+subj, true);
                                   ^ you forgot an equal sign here
```

So it should be,

```
xhttp.open("GET", "ajaxy/fred.php?q="+subj, true);
```

And second, remove `'` from `echo '$returntext;`, it should be `echo $returntext;`